# Namespace in php not working

Tags: php, namespaces

I recently learn how to use namespaces on the official site. However, it is not working for me.

I have created 2 files below to test.

**Example/ExampleClass.php**

```
<?php  
namespace Example;

class ExampleClass {

    public function __construct(){
        echo 'Example Class is used by namespace';
    }
}
```

**main.php**

```
<?php 
use Example\ExampleClass as ExampleClass;

$example_class = new ExampleClass;
```

When I complied, I got

> This page isn’t working 
>   localhost is currently unable to handle this
>   request. HTTP ERROR 500

This may be a stupid question but what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing `include` or `require` in your `main.php` script:

```
include_once('Example/ExampleClass.php');
```

> `use` doesn't include anything. It just imports the specified namespace (or class) to the current scope if they are before included

Comment: Is there any way to just use namespace without include or require? Something like include or require every time when namespace is used.

Comment: Nope. At least one time you must included it.

Comment: About your `HTTP 500 Error` this can be another issue. In my environement if I not include `ExampleClass.php` ... I got `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Example\ExampleClass' not found` ... So I have tried your `ExampleClass` and work as espected (if I have included it first)

Comment: Abut include You have one posibility to automatize Take a look here  (see examples): http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: I have remove 
`use Example\ExampleClass as ExampleClass;`
then add 
`require 'Example/ExampleClass.php';`

The error still occurs
But then I remove the line 
`namespace Example;` this time it works.
Seem like the problem is the namespace line
I don't know what is happening.

Comment: I have restarted the browser and it seems to work now.
Thank you very much for your help.